# I want to make it so if you enter the wrong text it will still work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, if-statement, input

```
question = input('Please choose one. add, times, divide, minus')

if (question=='add'):
if (question=='times'):
if (question=='divide'):
if (question=='minus'):
```

I want to make it so if I enter something else it will ask me to enter it again instead of error

Comment: use `else` condition

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Could someone also help me with writing my results to a csv file   

    file.write(question + " | " + name + "'s results: {0} correct, {1} incorrect/n".format(stats['correct'], stats['incorrect']))

thats what I have so far

Comment: Do not replace your question that already got answers with a new question that makes the answers meaningless.

Comment: Sorry It won't let me ask a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will continuously ping the user unless he/she enters the correct input ,

```
while True:
    question = input('Please choose one. add, times, divide, minus')

    if (question=='add'):
        #Do processing
        break
    elif (question=='times'):
        #Do processing
        break
    elif (question=='divide'):
        #Do processing
        break
    elif (question=='minus'):
        #Do processing
        break
    else:
        print "Please enter a valid input !"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `elif` to chain your conditions together; only one matching condition will then be picked:

```
if (question=='add'):
elif (question=='times'):
elif (question=='divide'):
elif (question=='minus'):
```

The added advantage is that you can now tack on an `else` block, to catch the case where the user picked *none of the above*:

```
if (question=='add'):
elif (question=='times'):
elif (question=='divide'):
elif (question=='minus'):
else:
```

You could put your question asking in an endless loop, and use `break` to step out of that loop, and perhaps use `continue` to restart the loop from the top:

```
while True:
    question = input('Please choose one. add, times, divide, minus')

    if (question=='add'):
        # 
    elif (question=='times'):
        #
    elif (question=='divide'):
        #
    elif (question=='minus'):
        # 
    else:
        print('Please enter a valid option!')
        continue

    # we got here, so we must've had a proper input
    break
```

Also see the canonical [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: In which case could you reach the `break` statement ? It seems that all non proper/unknown input would fall in the `else` statement

Comment: @bvidal: exactly, which uses `continue` to ask again. If you got proper input, the `break` is reached, after handling the input.

Comment: Ok so that avoid having the break statement in every `if/elif` statement. Got it!

Comment: @bvidal: exactly, otherwise you'd need 4 of them, one in each branch.

Comment: plus1 for handling that redundant break statements.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this does avoid redundancy, which is nice, but the comment that goes with it is not correct/precise enough - to me at least. Also, depending on what's in the `if` statements this may go against the idea of being explicit against implicit. What's your take on that ?

Comment: @bvidal: Personally, I'd farm out the prompting to a separate function that is given valid input options to check against. It'll only return if the user has given proper, valid input.

Answer (score 0):

To continue asking:

```
question = ''
while question not in ('add', 'times', 'divide', 'minus'):
    question = input('Please choose one. add, times, divide, minus')

if question == 'add':
     # do something
elif question == 'times':
     # do something
...
```

Note, that to interrupt the loop the answer must be one of the alternatives.